# How do you format a perl string?

Tags: perl

I'm in the midst of a perl crash course (our semester is about to end). Unfortunately, perl isn't exactly the easier language to learn and I've ran into a bit of trouble.

Our teach gave us a simple assignment, or so it seemed. We're supposed to take a 16 digit credit card number and print it out in 4 groups of 4 digits.

So for example 1234-1234-1234-1234 would be 1234 1234 1234 1234. The program is supposed to ignore any foreign character and only focus on digits.

Thus far I have managed to code this:

```
# Get input from user
print "\n\n";
print 'Please enter a string:  ';
chomp($inp = <>);
print "\nYou entered: $inp";
```

I've done some minor research and noticed \d is used for for digits so I imagine I would be coding something like \d\d\d\d \d\d\d\d etc, but, as I previously said I don't exactly understand what I am doing in perl. So I am hoping someone can explain the proper direction I need to take.

Thanks

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html

Comment: How would you write this in a language that you prefer?

Comment: Do you know what a regex is and how it would be used? Also always `use strict` and `warnings`

Comment: doing some more research so I can go /d{4} /d{4} /d{4} /d{4}  (for 16 digit card) - still trying to figure out how to implement it. Posted late - didn't know about use strict, just read about it, i'll be sure to add it

Comment: so you have several steps to do: get rid of any non-digits, check that there are 16 digits remaining, break them into groups of four, print them out with spaces between the groups.  focus on getting one step done before you start the next.

Comment: well I think I got the number part: \d{4})(\d{4})(\d{4})(\d{4})/$1 $2 $3 $4/;

Comment: Alright so this is what I have SO far: #!/usr/bin/perl

[code]print 'Please enter your card number: ';
chomp ($cc = <>);
$cc =~ s/(\d{4})(\d{4})(\d{4})(\d{4})/$1 $2 $3 $4/;
print "\nYou Entered: $cc";[/code] now I just need to figure out how to remove foreign objects

Comment: @JustinR: `tr/0-9//cd`

Comment: Edit: I fixed my problem

Comment: Or since you're familiar with s///, `s/\D//g`

Answer (score 1):

First, remove non-digits. (By the way, this makes the `chomp` redundant.)

- `$cc =~ s/[^0-9]//g;`
- `$cc =~ tr/0-9//cd;`

Then validate.

- `die("Invalid credit card number\n") if length($cc) != 16;`

Then, add in the spaces

- `$cc = join ' ', $cc =~ /[0-9]{4}/g;`
- `$cc = join ' ', unpack 'A4', $cc;`